# Disable storage of invisible files "._" on my cfs or smb network storage

Tags: macos, smb, filesystem, invisible-files

I use OS X Mavericks and have some company storage drives mounted (using smb or cfs).
(smb://username@address.path.toserver.com/directory/data).
When I work with files on the drive or copy files to the drive, some hidden files are created. Most of these files start with dot-dash `._` and then the filename of the original file, like:

```
._test001.png
._test002.png
._test003.png
```

And most of the times, the famous `._.DS_Store` and `.DS_Store` are also there.

On my Mac, these `.` dot items are invisible, but my windows colleagues do see these files. **How can I prevent OS X from making these strange invisible files?**

On [support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1629?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) (and other internet sources) you can find a 'defaults write' to disable the creation of .DS_Store files on your network drives. But this does not work in Mavericks:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true
```

For now I use this oneliner, but doing a `rm -rf` does feel wrong in this case.

```
find . -type f -name "._*" -exec rm "{}" \;
```

Edit: I don't want to delete the files or exclude them from copying. I want them not to be created in the first place.

Edit: I prefer a 'native' OS X solution over third party apps.

Edit: This questions has two answers, one for the ._ files and one for the .DS_Store files. The bounty is rewarded for `dot_clean`, this native command line app cleans all ._ files. Unfortunately is does not clear the .DS_Store files, this can effectively be done with Asepsis. Asepsis stores .DS_Stores in a fixed location, and not in the folder itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if these suggestions will solve your problem so leaving these in a comment. 1. Try TinkerTool http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html and use Finder > "Don't create hidden .DS_Store files over a network connection". 2. Try the Secrets System Preferences Pane http://secrets.blacktree.com and untick Finder > Use .DS_Stores on a network.

Comment: @gentlemanhog, I'll try your suggestions. But I do prefer a 'native' OS X solution over thirdparty apps.

Comment: @gentlemanhog, unfortunately your solutions do not work in Mavericks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I will admit, I hadn't noticed that the `defaults write` command stopped working in Mavericks.
However, when I DO clean network mounts, instead of your one liner `find` and `rm`, I use this:

```
dot_clean .
```

The manfile explains:

```
dot_clean -- Merge ._* files with corresponding native files.
```

I don't use the -m flag, but you may find it helpful in your situation.

```
-m      Always delete dot underbar files.
```

Here is another person actively trying to stop .DS_Store files from being created:
http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/ - looks like he doesn't want them on drives as much as he doesn't want them on the network!

Comment: This a the right tool for the job. Unfortunately this solution is 'post' mounting and needs to run after the mounting occurs. The asepsis does a better job (http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136558/55028) but is a third party app and only works on .DS_Store files, and only works for all .DS_Store files on every mount.

Answer (score 13):

Just tried, and this does work in Mavericks (at least for disabling .DS_Store not network shares):

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true
```

You just need to remember to restart Finder as well:

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: This does not work on El Capitan, for a Samba drive. `.DS_Store` files are still being created

Comment: The `.DS_Store` are not AppleDouble files, they're just "normal" invisible files that are created by the Finder. So, your seeing of those .DS_Store files is no indication whether the `DSDontWriteNetworkStores` works or not.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: "`seeing those .DS_Store files is no indication whether the DSDontWriteNetworkStores works or not`"  That's a **generous** interpretation of the `DSDontWriteNetworkStores` command - but then again [it does say](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102064), *"you can prevent macOS from reading .DS_Store files on SMB shares ..."* I s'pose if you can reconcile `DSDontWrite` with prevention of reading - maybe Apple has a job for you in their PR department?

Answer (score 5):

The `._` files are AppleDouble files that are used to store metadata like extended attributes, ACLs, file flags, and resource forks.

To delete them, run:

```
find . -name ._\* -delete
```

You can see if files have extended attributes, ACLs, or file flags with `ls -l@eO`. The `._` files are usually created because files have extended attributes. You can use `xattr -c` to delete extended attributes or `chmod -N` to delete ACLs. `cp -X` and `rsync` copy files without extended attributes, ACLs, file flags, or resource forks.

Comment: I do dont want to delete the files or exclude them from copying. I want them not to be created in the first place.

Comment: If your using the Finder, you cannot prevent them from being created.

Comment: @Fyrefly, but you can create them somewhere else. See Asepsis, http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136558/55028. So a 'native' solution might be possible as well

Answer (score 4):

As you would have to disable writing of hidden files on every Mac that could connect to your share, a better option would be to stop this at the share and not on the clients.

All you need to do is to edit your share config (for example in Linux in /etc/samba/smb.conf) and add the following option into your share config:

```
veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/
```

Now no Mac clients can save any files with those patterns to your share.

Comment: 'veto files' does not prevent files being written, it prevents users from **seeing** the files. Please refer to [samba.org](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html)

Comment: samba has the option "delete veto files = yes" though, which also delete them.

Comment: Unfortunately, `delete veto files = yes` does not delete those dot files, it just insures that you can delete a folder that contains files that have been hidden from view by the `veto files` option, so it does not accomplish what the OP was after (and for what I am also vainly searching for).

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this myself, *and* I realize the OP prefers native solutions, but nonetheless:

There's an app called [Asepsis](http://asepsis.binaryage.com) that works by redirecting creation of those files into a special folder, i.e. in a way preventing them from appearing.

Comment: This is a good tool for the job. Unfortunately this solution is a third party app and only works on .DS_Store files (not ._ files), and only works for all .DS_Store files on every mount. This is a good solution, but non native and non ._ files and therefor no bounty. sry.

Answer (score 2):

Not a native solution, nor does it *actually* prevent these files being written, but it does actively chase after them & delete as soon as they are written…

[BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/)

> BlueHarvest automatically removes .DS_Store and ._ AppleDouble files from your USB keys, SD cards, music players, file servers or any non Mac disk. BlueHarvest removes these items as they’re created or modified so you’ll always be metadata free without you needing to lift a finger.

No affiliation, I've just been using it quite successfully for several years.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not prevent that these files will be created. At least the Finder will create them.

Deleting these files will not help too - because the next time you access the volume and its folders on Mac, the Finder will create them again.

I am astonished that your Windows colleagues see these files. I am working for many years now with my Mac using Mac and Windows - and I never see these files. Neither on Mac nor on Windows.

These files are marked as "hidden" by default, and will not appear if you have Windows set to hide hidden files and folders.

Comment: I checked, and they do have disabled 'hide hidden files'. But this does not prevent them from being created. I think there is a way to fix this, as there was in OS 10.5 defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true

Comment: If they disabled (unchecked) 'hide hidden files' then it is just the other way: enable it. :-) And as I said: as far as I know there is no "native OS X solution" solution. And: you linked to an answer from "support.apple.com" which says: "Disabling the creation of .DS_Store files on remote file servers can cause unexpected behavior in the Finder". And: I would not suggest to install applications which promises to prevent it. As far as I know this can be very dangerous.

Comment: "this can be very dangerous" :) Now I really want these files gone! Seriously, .DS_Store files store Finder properties, and corrupted DS_Store files can do strange things indeed. I don't want corrupted DS_Store files, I want NO DS_Store files. I am not afraid of removing them. And back to my original question: How can I prevent OS X from making these strange invisible files? And with that I mean all ._ files and .DS_Store files. Nothing else.

Comment: It would be helpful for me (and may be you) if you would confirm that the people enabled (and not disabled) "hide hidden files". And I can understand that you do not want that these files will be created and that you want a native solution, but if there is no native solution then it does not help to say "but I want it".

Answer (score -2):

I found a very easy and free way to get rid go ._ files, especially from an external fat32 HD.

Launch [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) (free software). From Utilities, go to AppleDouble, select... the folder. Thats it!!!

Comment: The OP quite specifically states he doesn't want a clean-up tool, but one that prevents the files being written at all.